# ocultar / mostrar icono en toolbar

Tags: kotlin, fragment, toolbar

Tengo un activity donde cargo todo lo del toolbar. Mi inconveniente es que en el activity no uso ningún icono a la derecha como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando entro a un fragment necesito cargar a la derecha el icono del carrito de compras como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun he visto en algunas consultas, la mayoria de personas usan en el fragment el siguiente metodo para editar el toolbar

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
        requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()
        val menuItem: MenuItem? = menu.findItem(R.id.cart)
        menu.findItem(R.id.cart).isVisible = true
        menuItem?.icon = convertIconToImage(
            requireContext(),
            mainVM.count.value!!,
            R.drawable.cart)
        menu.findItem(R.id.cart).isVisible = true
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

pero en mi caso, no hace ninguna acción y tampoco ingresa a este método cuando se carga el fragment. De que otra forma podría intentar hacerlo?. Adiciono el xml del menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item
        android:title="carrito"
        android:id="@+id/cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/cart"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cambia la visualización de `android:visible="false"` a `android:visible="true"`, para que tu elemento sea visible de forma predeterminada.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item
        android:title="carrito"
        android:id="@+id/cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/cart"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```